# How can I dual boot 2 linux distros( Ubuntu and another) Keeping One as my primary and constantly change the second?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I would like to Dual boot my secondary laptop. I want to keep one Linux Distro (Lets take Ubuntu..!) as my daily driver and try out different distros like Linux Mint, Fedora, Manjaro....etc. How can I configure my GRUB for constantly changing secondary distro?? I don't want to keep common /home folder for them; I just want to try out different distros for a week or may be couple of weeks. Please suggest me a good way to do it.

Edit: I am having legacy BIOS in my Laptop.

Comment: I would recommend to use virtualization in this case. You can use various of pre-defined vagrant boxes to achieve your goal. Of course, in this case you don't have to modify your grub configuration at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Grub Customizer to easily configurate your GRUB, there is a link to a guide about installing and using grub customizer:
[Grub Customizer in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)